# Magento 2: How to remove input option from grid filter

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, uicomponent, filter

[image]

I want to remove some of filters from my grid in Magento 2 backend admin grid. Currently I have grid like displayed on image. But if I want to remove customer name how to do so.

please explain
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please remove filter tag from your ui_component grid from your column.

```
<item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item> remove this tag
```

For example:

OLDER:

```
<column name="subscriber_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="validate-identifier" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

NEW:

```
<column name="subscriber_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="validate-identifier" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
```

Comment: hii thaks it worked

Comment: can we make input type date thair in filter

Comment: That's nice news, you can change filter type by this option.

Comment: <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item> like here text is option. right?

Comment: like that what will for calender input

Comment: yeah right. <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item> AND <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item> etc...

Comment: tnks again worked like charm ;)